# Show/hide common input fields then post to php

Tags: php, jquery

I am developing a form for user and he wants the form fields to change according to a drop down menu. So if he choose "Library" for example as a facility name, he should inter its area, capacity, quantity and internet availability status. On the other hand if he select "Exhibition Area", he should inter its type, area, capacity, quantity and internet status. As you can see their is a common "duplicate" fields that result a problem in receiving inserted data in php.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- jQuery Validation Plugin 
hosted by Google API -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="addFacility-validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.viewMap = {
    'none' : $([]),
    'Library' : $('#Library'),
    'Clinic' : $('#Library'),
    'Indoor Playgrounds' : $('#Library'),
    'Outdoor Playgrounds' : $('#Library'),
    'Mosque' : $('#Library'),
    'Auditorium' : $('#Library'),
    'Ambulance' : $('#Ambulance'),
    'Exhibition Area' : $('#Exhibition,#Library'),
    'Cafeteria' : $('#Library'),
    'Shaded Barking Area' : $('#ShadedBarkingArea'),
    'Toilet' : $('#Toilet'),
    'Drinking Water Fountain' : $('#DrinkingWaterFountain'),
    'Green Areas' : $('#GreenAreas'),
    'Ground Water Tank' : $('#GroundWaterTank'),
    'Student Doom' : $('#StudentDoom'),
    'Student Residential Units' : $('#StudentDoom'),
    'Student Shaded Areas' : $('#StudentShadedAreas'),
  };

  $('#viewSelector').change(function() {
    // hide all
    $.each($.viewMap, function() { this.hide(); });
    // show current
    $.viewMap[$(this).val()].show();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    $dbhost="localhost";
    $dbuser="root";
    $con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser, "");
    if (!$con) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,'dahbulidings');

    if(isset($_GET['add']))
    {
        if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        {
            $name = addslashes ($_GET['name']);
            $type = addslashes ($_GET['type']);
            $area = addslashes ($_GET['area']);
            $capacity = addslashes ($_GET['capacity']);
            $quantity = addslashes ($_GET['quantity']);
            $internet = addslashes ($_GET['internet']);
            $available = addslashes ($_GET['available']);
            $comments = addslashes ($_GET['comments']);

        }
        else
        {
            $name = $_GET['name'];
            $type = $_GET['type'];
            $area = $_GET['area'];
            $capacity = $_GET['capacity'];
            $quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
            $internet = $_GET['internet'];
            $available = $_GET['available'];
            $comments = $_GET['comments'];
        }

        echo $b_id.$name.$type.$area.$capacity.$quantity.$internet.$available.$comments;
    }
?>
<div id="content">
  <h3>Facility Information</h3>
  <form action="test.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addFac-form" novalidate>
    <div class="formLayout">
      <div class="required">
        <label>Facility name</label>
        <select name="name" id="viewSelector">
          <option value="none"></option>
          <option value="Library">Library</option>
          <option value="Clinic">Clinic</option>
          <option value="Indoor Playgrounds">Indoor Playgrounds</option>
          <option value="Outdoor Playgrounds">Outdoor Playgrounds</option>
          <option value="Mosque">Mosque</option>
          <option value="Auditorium">Auditorium</option>
          <option value="Exhibition Area">Exhibition Area</option>
          <option value="Cafeteria">Cafeteria</option>
          <option value="Shaded Barking Area">Shaded Barking Area</option>
          <option value="Ambulance">Ambulance</option>
          <option value="Toilet">Toilet</option>
          <option value="Drinking Water Fountain">Drinking Water Fountain</option>
          <option value="Green Areas">Green Areas</option>
          <option value="Ground Water Tank">Ground Water Tank</option>
          <option value="Student Doom">Student Doom</option>
          <option value="Student Residential Units">Student Residential Units</option>
          <option value="Student Shaded Areas">Student Shaded Areas</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="Exhibition" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Type</label>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="Atrium">Atrium</option>
            <option value="Red Carpet">Red Carpet</option>
            <option value="Gallery C Ground Floor">Gallery C Ground Floor</option>
            <option value="Gallery B Ground Floor">Gallery B Ground Floor</option>
            <option value="Gallery C Third Floor">Gallery C Third Floor</option>
            <option value="Gallery B Third Floor">Gallery B Third Floor</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="Library" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Area</label>
          <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Capacity</label>
          <input type="text" name="capacity" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <select name="quantity">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Internet</label>
          <select name="internet">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="Available">Available</option>
            <option value="Not Available">Not available</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="Ambulance" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <select name="quantity">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="ShadedBarkingArea" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Area</label>
          <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Capacity</label>
          <input type="text" name="capacity" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <select name="quantity">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="Toilet" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Type</label>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="Single Surface Area">Single Surface Area</option>
            <option value="Common  Surface Area">Common  Surface Area</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Area</label>
          <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <select name="quantity">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="DrinkingWaterFountain" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <select name="quantity">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="GreenAreas" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Type</label>
          <select name="type">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="Fountain Area">Fountain Area</option>
            <option value="Bandar Bin Sultan Garden">Bandar Bin Sultan Garden</option>
            <option value="Gate 3 Area">Gate 3 Area</option>
            <option value="Gate 1 Area">Gate 1 Area</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="required">
          <label>Area</label>
          <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="GroundWaterTank" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Capacity</label>
          <input type="text" name="capacity" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="StudentDoom" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Availability</label>
          <select name="available">
            <option value="none"></option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="StudentShadedAreas" style="display:none">
        <div class="required">
          <label>Area</label>
          <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
        </div>
        <br>
        <label>Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
        <br>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" id="add">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/vxxue6d3/)

**When I echo all the form fields, I get nothing.**

**How to fix this ?**

Comment: Try putting your php code at the very beggining of file.

Comment: @ArekGorecki Although that didn't fix the problem but thanks

Comment: Errors? Can you add `if(isset($_GET)) { var_dump($_GET) }` up front, before the MySQL Connection.

Comment: @Twisty Adding this show array(0) { }, btw I aimed to use POST but i tried GET to check my data at the url, whitch shows for "library case" name=Library&type=none&area=100+Km&capacity=50&quantity=1&internet=Available&quantity=none&area=&capacity=&quantity=none&type=none&area=&quantity=none&comments=&quantity=none&comments=&type=none&area=&comments=&capacity=&comments=&available=none&comments=&area=&comments=&add=Add

Comment: As what you can see fields of other facilities override the values of the selected one. Although I hide them in jquery - this is the problem

Comment: If `$_GET` is empty, then you're not going to be able to do anything with it. What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I expect to get ($name.$type.$area.$capacity.$quantity.$internet.$available.$comments) No matter if they appears ( I recive thier values) or hidden (I recive null ) by the dropdown menu (Facility name) but they always get override by the hidden fields just because they have the same name.In the url they appears good (name=Library&type=none&area=100+Km&capacity=50&quantity=1&internet=Available) then they get override by other hidden fields and I get nothing !!

Comment: @Twisty For example: what would you do if I asked you to develop a form that includes a drop down menu of two choice. If I select the first one, you should ask me to fill in 4 input fields and if I select the second one, you should ask me to fill in 3 input fields of the first option ( meaning missing one of them) and with one more extra different input field ? so If you named the form input fields. First option has val1,val2,val3,val4 and Second option has val1,val2,val3,vla5. How you will manage posting val1 to val5 to php ?

Comment: @AsmaaAlharbi I could develop a few ways to accomplish this. I could populate all the various options, hide them, and them reveal them as the user make changes, using JavaScript. I could also create the first portion of the form and then using AJAX get more options based on the users selections. Then when all the data is collected, I would post the resulting form to a handler, PHP. You suggest the values are in the URL, meaning you'd use `$_GET` to find them. Your `$_GET` is not populated, so you need to find out why and address that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue simply by changing the fields names to be unique. Then, I wort a switch of the facility name (the only field that has a unique name in my old form). In each case I was receiving it's corresponding input fields and inserting them. its wasn't a big headache as what I have imagined.

Answer (score 0):

Had to sit and stare at this for a bit. I would separate your PHP From your HTML. Let's call them form.html and handler.php for the case of this answer.

form.html would have the form, like so:

```
<div id="content">
     <h3>Facility Information</h3>
    <form action="handler.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addFac-form" novalidate>
        <div class="formLayout">
            <div class="required">
                <label>Facility name</label>
                <select name="name" id="viewSelector">
                    <option value="none"></option>
                    <option value="Library">Library</option>
                    <option value="Clinic">Clinic</option>
                    <option value="Indoor Playgrounds">Indoor Playgrounds</option>
                    <option value="Outdoor Playgrounds">Outdoor Playgrounds</option>
                    <option value="Mosque">Mosque</option>
                    <option value="Auditorium">Auditorium</option>
                    <option value="Exhibition Area">Exhibition Area</option>
                    <option value="Cafeteria">Cafeteria</option>
                    <option value="Shaded Barking Area">Shaded Barking Area</option>
                    <option value="Ambulance">Ambulance</option>
                    <option value="Toilet">Toilet</option>
                    <option value="Drinking Water Fountain">Drinking Water Fountain</option>
                    <option value="Green Areas">Green Areas</option>
                    <option value="Ground Water Tank">Ground Water Tank</option>
                    <option value="Student Doom">Student Doom</option>
                    <option value="Student Residential Units">Student Residential Units</option>
                    <option value="Student Shaded Areas">Student Shaded Areas</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div id="Exhibition" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Type</label>
                    <select name="type">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="Atrium">Atrium</option>
                        <option value="Red Carpet">Red Carpet</option>
                        <option value="Gallery C Ground Floor">Gallery C Ground Floor</option>
                        <option value="Gallery B Ground Floor">Gallery B Ground Floor</option>
                        <option value="Gallery C Third Floor">Gallery C Third Floor</option>
                        <option value="Gallery B Third Floor">Gallery B Third Floor</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="Library" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Area</label>
                    <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Capacity</label>
                    <input type="text" name="capacity" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <select name="quantity">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Internet</label>
                    <select name="internet">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="Available">Available</option>
                        <option value="Not Available">Not available</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="Ambulance" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <select name="quantity">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="ShadedBarkingArea" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Area</label>
                    <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Capacity</label>
                    <input type="text" name="capacity" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <select name="quantity">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="Toilet" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Type</label>
                    <select name="type">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="Single Surface Area">Single Surface Area</option>
                        <option value="Common  Surface Area">Common Surface Area</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Area</label>
                    <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <select name="quantity">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>Comments</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="DrinkingWaterFountain" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Quantity</label>
                    <select name="quantity">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>Comments</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="GreenAreas" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Type</label>
                    <select name="type">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="Fountain Area">Fountain Area</option>
                        <option value="Bandar Bin Sultan Garden">Bandar Bin Sultan Garden</option>
                        <option value="Gate 3 Area">Gate 3 Area</option>
                        <option value="Gate 1 Area">Gate 1 Area</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Area</label>
                    <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>Comments</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="GroundWaterTank" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Capacity</label>
                    <input type="text" name="capacity" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>Comments</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="StudentDoom" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Availability</label>
                    <select name="available">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>Comments</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="StudentShadedAreas" style="display:none">
                <div class="required">
                    <label>Area</label>
                    <input type="text" name="area" dir="ltr">
                </div>
                <br>
                <label>Comments</label>
                <input type="text" name="comments" dir="ltr">
                <br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" name="add" id="add">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

So we change the form a little so it does POST and we direct it to post the data to handler.php. So now we need to setup that file to catch the data posted, and add it to the database.

I noticed your script has no Query yet you connect to the database. So that is a problem. Here's what I can suggest and you'll have to fix it to match your environment/database.

```
<?php 
// Check if we got a submission and then connect to the database
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    // Conditionally set the variable or a Default value
    $name = isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:"none";
    $type = isset($_POST['type'])?$_POST['type']:"none";
    $area = isset($_POST['area'])?$_POST['area']:"none";
    $capacity = isset($_POST['capacity'])?$_POST['capacity']:"none";
    $quantity = isset($_POST['quantity'])?$_POST['quantity']:0;
    $internet = isset($_POST['internet'])?$_POST['internet']:"none";
    $available = isset($_POST['available'])?$_POST['available']:"no";
    $comments = isset($_POST['comments'])?$_POST['comments']:"none";
} else {
    die("Form data not submitted.\r\n");
}
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, "", "dahbuildings");
if (!$con){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
// create a prepared statement
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO tableName (name, type, area, capacity, internet, available, comments) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    // bind parameters for markers
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssisss", $name, $type, $area, $capacity, $internet, $available, $comments);
    // execute query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo mysqli_insert_id($con) . ": $name, $type, $area, $capacity, $quantity, $internet, $available, $comments";
    // close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You can now also post the data via AJAX to this form handler, process the results, and display the results or allow the user to add another.

Comment: Sr thank you so much for your effort. However, my script has a connection to db (at my php code). Also, your solution didn't work nothing inserted although I didn't get any errors. Did that work with you ? And do I have to use AJAX ?